# Sharekit Facebook error

Tags: objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I am using ShareKit.

It's working properly with Twitter API, but getting error in Facebook API.

In SHKConfig

```
#define SHKFacebookKey              @"my Facebook Key"
#define SHKFacebookSecret           @"my Facebook Secret"
```

Error image

[image: facebook-error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using old original share kit, which contains obsolete version of Facebook iOS sdk (FBConnect). I suggest that you use updated [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). Its installation has changed a lot, so make sure you carefully follow [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). Best bet is to readd new ShareKit from scratch, if you decide to use it.